# Prolonging the time between death and loading of the latest save game

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, pc

Is there a way to prolong the time between dying and the automatic loading of the last saved game?

I'm currently jumping off the Throat of the World to see the rag doll physics and sometimes the game loads while the rag doll is still moving or even falling.

Comment: I think your character needs to call the Samaritans :P

Comment: Fus Rah Dah!!!!

Comment: Might god mode help with that? I'm not sure if the rag dolls you describe only show when the character has already died, which god mode would actively prevent from happening.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like you want to increase the duration of the *death cam*, which [Death Cam Duration Options](https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/242) can prolong. There's even an insane thirty minute version!

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way is to buy a horse from some stables, and to fast travel to where you want to test from. Then ride the horse off your selected cliff.

You can occasionally survive a fall even if your horse dies, so Bethesda stopped any saves from loading during your decent and only registers survival/death upon the character being stationary.

Enjoy your horse killing and character destroying.

Comment: I do this from the High Hrothgar courtyard (not accessible by horse AFAICT) and I need Whirlwind Sprint to get the initial distance for a long jump. Will try it though and see how it goes.